# This operation requires the page to be asynchronous (the Async attribute must be set to true).

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to execute an asynchronous task on my Azure hosted webpage inside the Page_Load method. However I'm getting the above error. I have set the Async property of the page to true in the aspx file and still no luck.

ASP Header Code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="SalesAndCCFAQ.FAQ" Async ="true"%>
```

Page_Load Code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(test));
        Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks();
        //Only need to fill catDropDown when the page is first directed to
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            fillCatDropDown();
            //Show who is currently logged in
            currentUserLabel.Text += HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;           
        }
        if (GlobalUse.external == true)
            {
                whichApproved = "approvedExternal = 1";
                greenKeyImage.Visible = false;
                greenKeyLabel.Visible = false;
                yellowKeyImage.Visible = false;
                yellowKeyLabel.Visible = false;
                redKeyImage.Visible = false;
                redKeyLabel.Visible = false;

            }
            else
            {
                whichApproved = "approvedInternal = 1";
            }
        //String to be added to main query if a category is selected
        filterCatQuery = "cid = (SELECT cid FROM Category WHERE name = '" + catDropDown.Text + "')";
    }
```

Page_PreInit Code:

```
    protected void Page_PreInit()
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (GlobalUse.external == true)
            {
                this.MasterPageFile = "~/SiteExternal.Master";
            }
        }
    }
```

Asynchronous function that is called:

```
    protected async Task test()
    {
        if (GlobalUse.external != null)
            return;
        await GlobalUse.isUserExternalGroup(); //This method sets GlobalUse.external
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx"); //Refresh to call the PreInit Code again
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Set Async to true as below in the page.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" Async="true" MasterPageFile="~/XXX.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="XXX.aspx.cs" Inherits="XXX"
ValidateRequest="false" meta:resourcekey="XXX" %>
```

Comment: The OP specified that this was already set. "I have set the Async property of the page to true in the aspx file and still no luck." and even provided a code snippet showing this. Perhaps suggest something different in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

The reason this error was being thrown is because it was my Default page. The way I fixed it was by creating a blank Default page which then redirects to my desired homepage upon it being loaded. I will leave this here as it may be of use to someone and I believe it is quite a unique case.

Answer (score -1):

You can write  this.AsyncMode = true; under page load to allow Async tasks execution.